# How To Change Text Color Of Preference In Androidx

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to change text color for Preference in Preference.xml file

XML Code

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.preference.Preference
        android:key="pref_entries"
        android:title="@string/settings_entries"
        android:summary="0"
        android:enabled="true"
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false" />
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

I Tried adding textcolor in xml file but it is not working

Java Code

```js
 prefEntries = pm.findPreference(Const.PREF_ENTRIES);
```

How to Change the pref text color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this customize PreferenceCategory class :

```
public class MyPreferenceCategory extends PreferenceCategory {
    public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyPreferenceCategory(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

and add this at your Pref.xml file :

```
<ali.UI.Customize.MyPreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_server" />
```

Method 2 :
An easy way to do this is to set the custom layout for the `preferenceCategory` here:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/preferences_category"
    android:title="Privacy">
```

An easy way to do this is to set the custom layout for the preferenceCategory here:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:layout="@layout/preferences_category"
    android:title="Privacy" >
```

Then set your code inside your `preferences_category` layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:textColor="@color/deep_orange_500"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAllCaps="true"/>
```

Comment: but i am also using summary there, it has 2 textview

Comment: Follow method 2 then.

Comment: Super method 2 works also on `androidx.preference.*`